# Change value in one column for every distinct value in another column. SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table with multiple columns. One column is called question and another is called group. I have 34 unique values for question and within each question I have multiple groups. For each question I have a specific group value I want to replace.

For example:

| Group | Question |
| --- | --- |
| one | string? |
| two | string? |

group = one can occur multiple times, just like two, three etc. The value in group I want to change is 'beta'. It occurs 5 times per question and I need to change it to the distinct other values of group. So I get another one, another two etc. The same thing needs to happen for each question in the table.

Comment: I have been able to solve it :) 
` WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Question ORDER BY Group) AS rn,
    CONCAT('group_', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Question ORDER BY Group)) AS new_group
  FROM table
  WHERE Group = 'beta'
)
UPDATE cte
SET Group = new_group;
`